# ID of parent Menu

Tags: menus, sub-menu

I'm trying to assign a different ID to each sub-menu wordpress generates using the wp_nav_menu function. As it is, wordpress assigns the same class (sub-menu) to every sub menu generated.

```
<ul class="sub-menu"></ul>
```

I'd like to have it generate something like:

```
<ul class="sub-menu" id="xx"></ul>
```

I have a custom walker in my theme function file in order to modify the output, but I have no idea how to get, say the ID of the parent menu item and assign it to the UL output.

Any help is appreciated!

*edit* Walker's below:

```
/**Custom walker**/
class description_walker extends Walker {
var $tree_type = array( 'post_type', 'taxonomy', 'custom' );
var $db_fields = array( 'parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id' );
function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu\" id=\"wut\">\n";
}
function end_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
}
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

    $class_names = $value = '';

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
    $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
    $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
}

function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth) {
    $output .= "</li>\n";
}
}
```

Comment: Paste your walker in here.

Comment: The walker is pretty much the same as the default one:

Comment: And you want every reader or possible answerer to go to core and check how the default walker looks like?

Comment: no, I ran out of characters via comments..edited my original post.

Comment: Was meant that way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the following

```
 <script>
$(function(){
    var i =0;
 $('ul.sub-menu').addClass (function(idx) {

     return "item-" + idx;
 });
 });
 </script>
```

It adds a class of item-0, item-1, etc to each sub-menu it finds.